# "Portal" with multi-apps

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing by Openui5 a portal. My portal have 2 apps. I I have organized the code in folders:

```
root
  |
  |____app1
  |____app2
  |
  |____appN
```

In each app folder I have "master" folder, "detail" folder...etc..
What is the best way to organize the code?

Now I have an external structure of SplitView from which I call the sub-apps 
(simply, when I select the app name from the list in the master column I replace the general master-detail pages - or the current app master-detail pages - with master-datail pages of the app selected)

Thi is the right way to develop a multi-app "portal"?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the worst approach :)

You might also want to think about using [UI5s Component concept](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/301b05f212334a66b1a2bc5411a6c030.html). It allows for a better separation of apps by providing dedicated Router and EventBus for every component. It also isolates the sub-apps models from each other so that you can have models with same name in every component (handy for i18n/ResourceModel). A component does not even have to live within the same location.

The perfect match for what you plan to do but might be a little oversized though since placing different subviews (master/detail) from a component into the parent component can get a bit tricky.

GL
Chris