# Use Homepage of Sap Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5

I see the "Homepage" of Sap Fiori Launchpad as start-page. http://experience.sap.com/fiori-guidelines/FioriLaunchpad/17_Fiori_Launchpad-Home_Page.html
Can I do the same thing with OpenUI5?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can ;)

Guess this relates to your question here: ["Portal" with multi-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466032/portal-with-multi-apps)

As I already mentioned there the [UI5 Component concept](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/958ead51e2e94ab8bcdc90fb7e9d53d0.html) is a good place to start. Furthermore check out [sap.m.TileContainer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.TileContainer.html) and [sap.m.StandardTile](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardTile.html). TileContainer already comes with an edit mode that allows for deletion and configuration per drag'n'drop. The tiles you see on your link are partially contained in the sap.suite packages and not part of OpenUI5. The container you see on Launchpad Homepage is a [sap.ui.unified.Shell](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.Shell.html) -> [Unified Shell Demo](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/unified/Shell.html?sap-ui-debug=true&sap-ui-language=de-DE&sap-ui-accessibility=true&sap-ui-jqueryversion=1.10.2&sap-ui-theme=sap_bluecrystal)

BR
Chris

Comment: Can I use `sap.m.Shell` ? or only `sap.ui.unified.Shell` ? Difference?

Comment: Sure you can. It looks differently and sap.ui.unified.Shell has some extra features. Added a demo link in my answer.

Comment: Is there source for the Unified Shell Demo?

Comment: Dear @cschuff,  How can I access the code of the Demo.